# knnsearch - how to connect points xi and xj if xi is one of the 5 nearest neighbors of xj (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab

I have a data matrix which contains 200 data points in 3 dimensional feature space. Basically the rows are only 3 but columns will be 200 and each column represents a data point.

I need to construct a graph based on the following two different criteria.

a. connect points xi and xj if xi is one of the 5 nearest neighbors of xj

b. connect points xi and xj if their distance is less than 300

For a. I am planning to use knnsearch by running two for loops as shown below

```
for j = 1:200,
for i = 1:200
[idx,d] = knnsearch(X_data(:,i), X_data(:,j), 'k', 5);
end
end
```

Is the above approach correct? I am confused since the data represents points in 3D space.

For b. is there a MATLAB function which i can use?

Also how do i join the points to make a graph?

Comment: `knnsearch` is the correct choice. Instead of giving one column at a time, you can do: `knnsearch(X_data.',X_data.',200);`. Notice the transpose - `.'` - and that I am asking for `200` neighboring points. So that you also get distances with all the points. Then you can use two for loops to create a graph satisfying your conditions. Graph can be a `200x200` matrix where element `(i,j) = 1` if `x_i` and `x_j` are connected, else 0.

Comment: Is the last parameter (200) "Scale"?

Comment: In `knnsearch`, the last parameter 200 means I am asking for `200` nearest neighboring points for each point in `X_data`.

Comment: Eventhough i need the 5 nearest neighbours, do i have to give 200?.

Comment: The for loop needs to be run on the transposed matrix?

Comment: I gave 200 because of your second condition i.e. what if 6th neighbor too was closer than 300? In the worst case, it may also happen that 200th neighbor is closer than 300? I transposed the matrix in `knnsearch` because samples are along the rows and features are along the columns in `knnsearch`. You just need for loops to test if pair of neighbors satisfy either of the conditions. You don't need to run for loops on the `X_data` matrix at all.

Comment: Index returned by knnsearch contains  all the indices of the nearest neighbors. So the loops need to be for the return value of knnsearch. Sorry this part is not clear to me.Any pseudo code would help.